# Sequence of differentiable functions that converges pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem :[image]

Theorem 9.35
[image]

Here is what I have so far. I'm stuck though

Proof:
Suppose that $f_n$ are differentiable for all $n\geq 1$. Suppose further that $\{f'_n | 
\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ is uniformly convergent to $g(x)$. Suppose further that the sequence $\{f_n(0)\}$ converges pointwise to $f(0)$. We want to show $\{f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ converges pointwise. Let $\epsilon>0$ We see that $f_n(x)-f_n(0)$ =$\int_0^x f'_n(x) dx$. It follows that we have a sequence of integrable functions and it follows by theorem 9.35 that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^x f'_n(x)+\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(0)$. It follows by assumption that we get know $\lim_{n\to\infty}= G(x)-G(0)+f(0)$. (We see $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^x f'_n(x)=\int_0^x g(x)=G(x)-G(0)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus and that $g(x)$ is continuous as well.). Let $f(x)=  G(x)-G(0)+f(0)$ and we get that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$. Thus $f_n(x)$ converges point wise to $f(x)$.

Im not sure what I have is correct and I know that I have things mixed up in my proof. Basically I need my proof assessed. Thanks

Comment: This is correct, but there are notational conflicts in the integral, and using the fundamental theorem of Calculus isn't necessary.

Comment: Read p. 6 of this [pdf](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~srg/courses/ma403-2008/uniconv.pdf) by B.V.Limaye.

Comment: What type of notational conflicts?